# pssh on mac 10.14 "Command not specified"

Tags: macos, ssh, pssh

I have installed pssh 2.3.1 on my mac mojave 10.14

```
brew install pssh
pssh --version
2.3.1
```

pssh --help also works fine. But when I try this:

```
pssh -H "10.65.8.50 10.65.8.45" -l dev
Usage: pssh [OPTIONS] command [...]

pssh: error: Command not specified.
```

I have python 3.7.5 installed. 
What am I doing wrong here?? :)

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: you're not specifying a command. `pssh` runs a command on one or more hosts; you need to tell it what command to run.

Comment: So with my bad memory csshx what was I was looking for.. I just could for god sake not remember the name :)

Comment: But at least now I also learned a little about pssh 

`pssh -H "10.65.8.50 10.65.8.45" -l dev "sudo puppet-update"`